# How to use natsort in different language?

Tags: php, sorting, utf-8

I'm trying to sort an array using natsort/natcasesort. But I'm having trouble with non-English (In Turkish) characters. This is the only option that works for me at the moment. How can I overcome this problem?
For example, the array looks like this:

```
   $texts= array("A","Ü","Ç","Ş","Ğ");
    natcasesort($texts);
    echo '<pre>'; print_r($files); echo '</pre>';
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => A
    [2] => Ç
    [1] => Ü
    [4] => Ğ
    [3] => Ş
)


$all_characters = [ "ğ", "Ğ", "ç", "Ç", "ş", "Ş", "ü", "Ü", "ö", "Ö", "ı", "İ" ];
    
$alphabet_all = "AaBbCcÇçDdEeFfGgĞğHhIıİiJjKkLlMmNnOoÖöPpQqRrSsŞşTtUuÜüVvWwXxYyZz";
$small_letters = array("İ","I","Ş","Ğ","Ö","Ü","Ç");
$capital_letters = array("i","ı","ş","ğ","ö","ü","ç");
```

How should it be ?
A, Ç, Ğ, Ş, Ü

Comment: What's the use case here? Natural sort is designed to cope with numbers in strings (so `v1.2` comes before `v1.10`). Do you have strings with Turkish words **and** numbers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Natsort is not suitable for language-specific sorting. That's what the [Collator](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.collator.php) class is for.

```
$all_characters = [ "ğ", "Ğ", "ç", "Ç", "ş", "Ş", "ü", "Ü", "ö", "Ö", "ı", "İ" ];

$collator = new Collator('tr_TR');

//The following line is only required if natsort is desired
$collator->setAttribute(Collator::NUMERIC_COLLATION, Collator::ON);

$collator->sort($all_characters);

echo implode(', ',$all_characters);
//ç, Ç, ğ, Ğ, ı, İ, ö, Ö, ş, Ş, ü, Ü
```

Comment: To whoever googles here: please be aware that `Collator` does not produce [natural sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_sort_order).

Comment: The behavior of natsort can be achieved by setting special attributes.